# jQuery working in JSFiddle but getting an empty array in website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

To give you a brief understanding on what I am trying to accomplish. I have an HTML which is dynamically generated. I need to convert that HTML into a specific JSON format. I have the code here in JSFiddle.

```
[link]: http://jsfiddle.net/X3p47/2/

function walk(node, result) {
var pages = jQuery("[data-role='page']");
pages.each(function () {
    var obj = {};
    console.log("Inside");
    obj.text = $(this).attr('id');
    obj.isFolder = true;
    obj.isExpanded = true;
    obj.children = findChild(this);
    result.push(obj);
});
//This is how I am calling the walk function
var a = [];
var testVal = localStorage.getItem( 'htmlValue' );
walk($.parseHTML(testVal), a);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

The code works fine and all, but the problem is that when I deploy the javascript (the above mentioned one) in my jsp page(name of my jsp page is dataMapping.jsp) it's taking the HTML of dataMapping rather than the HTML which I am supplying. If anyone could give me some inputs would be greatly appreciated.

The part where you see var pages = jQuery("[data-role='page']"); is basically becoming null, because it's taking the html of my page which is dataMapping.jsp

Comment: Debugging starts with your developer console. Any errors? Are you running this code after the page has loaded instead of immediately in the `<head>`?

Comment: Nope, no Errors. This is not written in the head. It's in the body, inside <scripts>

Comment: As you can see from the JSFiddle page, it works without any problems... The only problem is that the walk function as I have mentioned above is taking the HTML from the entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making this modification to your code. Rather than pages.each(function) try this

```
$each.(node, function(){
```